# html table board game prevent player from crossing empty tiles

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to code a board game using an HTML table and pure javascript. I'm using classes `.ground` and `.empty` to define which tiles are part of the board and which ones are not.

```
<tr>
  <td class="ground">7</td>
  <td class="empty">(8)</td>
  <td class="empty">(9)</td>
  <td class="ground">10</td>
</tr>
```

Player can only move to `.ground` tiles using whatever direction he wants :

```
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].addEventListener('click', playerMove, false);
}
function playerMove(e) {
    player.style.position = "absolute";
    player.style.top = e.target.offsetTop + 10 + "px";
    player.style.left = e.target.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}
```

My problem is to prevent `#player` div from crossing `.empty` tiles when it's moving to the clicked tile. When I click tile 22 for instance, `#player` will cross tile (8) and (15) which are not part of the board.
Simply disabling diagonal moves won't solve the problem because it won't prevent the player to cross empty tiles horizontally or vertically.

I guess I would need my function to 'know' whether the player is about to cross an empty tile while it's moving by comparing its position to the .empty tiles position but I have no idea how to do that or if it is even possible without using canvas (which I don't want to use).

Is what I'm trying to do possible without using canvas or third-party libraries? Or do I have to go with a different approach?

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/t40tq2ur/1/

Comment: Your approach is definitely possible without canvas or 3rd-party libraries. All your cells (boxes) are a fixed with, so you should be able to easily calculate if an empty cell would be crossed before the red box is actually moved. There are multiple ways you could accomplish this. BTW, bravo for doing this from scratch!

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to get better at javascript so this project is a good way for me to learn. I'm still unsure of how to detect if the red box is crossing the empty cells though. I tried to store my empty cells position in an array while using a setTimeout function to check if the player offset is colliding with them, but it didn't really work as I expected. I guess the best way to handle this would be to write a function which calculates the player path before it starts moving but that's exactly where I'm stuck. I would greatly appreciate if you had any suggestion or doc I might read

Comment: You can allow player to move only in horizontal or vertical line and check in between slides is that empty or not .. 
this may help